# c++ - Statement returning a pointer - explanation how it works and why

Tags: c++

I have a List.h and Node.h, and in List.h I write:

```
Node *List::getNewNode(const int &value){
    return new Node(value);
}
```

I understand that the function returns `Node`, but I don't understand why before the word `List` has a statement about a pointer, can I get an explanation please?

Comment: What do you think the `new` operator returns again?

Comment: pointer to node?

Comment: Exactly. Your question is answered :3

Comment: If you change your perspective just a little bit, the `*` isn't before `List` but after `Node`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function does not return a `Node`, but a `Node *`, or a pointer to a `Node`. To be fully clear about what types are being used here, you could rewrite it as:

```
Node * List::getNewNode(const int &value) {
    Node * ptrToReturn = new Node(value);
    return ptrToReturn;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The pointer symbol belongs to `Node` and not to `List`. Hence the return type is:
`Node*`
and the class method implementation is for:

`List::getNewNode`.

To understand, you may use `typedef`:

`typedef Node* PNode;`

And implement it this way:

```
PNode List::getNewNode(const int value) {
    PNode node = new Node(value);
    return node;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `new` operator allocates size for an instance of the class `Node` on the heap and calls the class' constructor to initialize that memory.  It then returns a pointer to the newly constructed instance.  This code receives that pointer and returns it to the caller... so the method is declared to return a pointer to a Node or Node*.  You might want to consider it as `Node* List::getNewNode...` but it's idiomatic to put in the space resulting in the code you presented.